# Android - draw9patch should help me? background of textview

Tags: android, view, background, textview, imageview

I need to set background of the TextView without stretching like this: [image]

I tried draw9patch but seems that it doesn't do that work. How can I reach this efect? I could also use ImageView, but I don't know how I can add text in ImageView (I cannot use layout or two views... image and text need to be in one view)

Comment: Is that square on left different in color from rest of `TextView`?

Comment: this image needs to imitate a checkbox. If I use a checkbox than I cannot implement setOnItemClickListener on the view behind the first one, which contains "undo" button. I don't like this solution, but I didn't find better one. I use android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo.

Comment: Then what you have written is wrong. That's not the background of `TextView`, it is checkbox

Comment: I had checkbox before I wanted to implement SwipeToDelete like in Google. Than I have problem with ClickListener, because I have two of them. That's why I need to avoid to use one clicklistener on checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use ***drawableLeft***
something like this :

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/question_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint=" your question"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

Comment: EditText unfortunately also prevents to use extra ClickListener. But drawableLeft with TextView doest excatly what I need :) drawableLeft ... so simple

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a button and dont set any click listeners for it..:
Here is the code:

```
  Button btnIconTxt=new Button(context);
  btnIconTxt.setId(id);
  //this aligns a image to the left of ur text view(This the important line).
  btnIconTxt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmapOfYourImage), null, null, null);

  btnIconTxt.setText(message);
  btnIconTxt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, sizeInPx);
  btnIconTxt.setWidth(widthInPx);
  btnIconTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);

  int currentApi = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
  if(currentApi >= 16)
    btnIconTxt.setBackground(btnColor);
  else
    btnIconTxt.setBackgroundDrawable(btnColor);

  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams SDISP_params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  btnIconTxt.setLayoutParams(params1);
  //U can set the x and y margin for this button using 
  //params1.leftMargin = xPixels;
 // params1.topMargin = yPixels;
  yourParentLayout.addView(btnIconTxt);
```

Comment: I am afraid I will not bo able to implement setOnItemClickListener on the view behind first view. I tried with checkbox (than I have text and "my image"), but setOnItemClickListener didn't work with it

Comment: u can mimic the tick mark: by changing the image when the button is clicked

Comment: Yes, this I want to do. But I cannot have any extra clicklistener. I will try with button which you have shown.